# Trying to pass and print string into a linked list

Tags: c, string, linked-list

So, I am trying to create a `linked List` where i take in strings from user then add them to the list and then delete the data at position 2. But i am having trouble with `scanf` (clarified in the output section) and also in the `printing` section. Any help would be appreciated.

The code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    char *data;
    char *begin;
    char *end;
    char *posi;
    struct node *link;
};

struct node *add_begin(struct node *head, char *data) {
    struct node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->link = head;
    return ptr;
}

struct node *add_end(struct node *head, char *data) {
    struct node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));

    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->link = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        return ptr;
    } else {
        struct node *temp = head;
        while (temp->link != NULL) {
            temp = temp->link;
        }
        temp->link = ptr;
        return head;
    }
}

void add_at_post(struct node* head, char *data, int pos){
    struct node *ptr=head;
    struct node *ptr2=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr2->data=data;
    ptr2->link=NULL;
    
    pos--;
    while(pos !=1){
        ptr=ptr->link;
        pos--;
    }
    ptr2->link=ptr->link;
    ptr->link=ptr2;
}

void delete_post(struct node* head, int position){
    struct node*current= head;
    struct node*previous= head;
    
    if(head==NULL){
        printf("is empty\n");
    }
    else if (position==1){
        head=current->link;
        free(current);
        current=NULL;
    }
    else{
        while(position!=1){
    previous=current;
    current=current->link;
    position--;
    }
    previous->link=current->link;
    free(current);
    current=NULL;
    }
}

int main() {
    struct node *head = NULL;
    char *data;
    printf("Print at begin");
    scanf("%s",data);
    head = add_begin(head,data);//print at beginning of list
    printf("Print at end");
    scanf("%s",data);
    head = add_end(head, data);//print at end of list
    printf("Print at Position 2");
    scanf("%s",data);
    add_at_post(head,data,2);//print at position 2
    delete_post(head,2);
    
    for (struct node *ptr = head; ptr; ptr = ptr->link) {
        printf("%s\n", ptr->data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The Expected Output

```
Print at begin
xxx
Print at end
yyy
Print at Position 2
ZZZ

xxx
zzz
```

The output I get. It calls the first `scanf` but skips the `other 2`. Then ends the RUN.

```
Print at begin 
xxx
Print at end 
Print at Position 2
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",data);` You must initialize `data` to point to valid memory before this. Writing to a memory location you don't own invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `char *data` is not initialized. Your code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: You probably need to make a copy of the data when you are storing a pointer to a buffer.

Answer (score 1):

This code is invalid in many places:

1. `data` does not reference valid memory

```
    char *data;
    printf("Print at begin");
    scanf("%s",data);
```

2. you should allocate memory for `ptr->data` and copy as `data` may reference the same location on every call.
3. You do not check result of the `malloc`